# pipe stuck in read (C - system calls)

Tags: c, pipe, system-calls

This the first time for me using C and so it has been very difficult so far. 
My program reads a file.txt.
In the first line there is the number of childs that i have to create(var: NPROC) and in the remaining lines i have to read the child's process id, two integers and a character that is the operation that i have to calculate:
ex:

```
NPROC
(id) (n1) (op) (n2)
2
2 3 + 1
1 5 / 2
2 9 * 3
```

I have to send the operations (line by line) to the child using a message queue (which works perfectly) and then the child should send back the results using a pipe.

this is the code:

(father)

```
//other code
for(i=0; i < NPROC; i++) {

    if(pipe(p) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    switch(currentPid = fork()){
        case 0:

            execl("./child", "./child", NULL);

            return 0;
        case -1:
            printf("Error when forking\n");
            break;
        default:

            // in the father
            childrenPids[i] = currentPid; // store current child pid
            wait(NULL);

            printf("\nParentpid:  %d, Childpid: %i \n", getpid(), currentPid);

            //close(p[1]);

            if(read(p[0], &val, sizeof(val) == -1){
                perror("read()\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            printf("Parent(%d) received value: %d\n", getpid(), val);

            break;         
    }

   //other code


(child)
 //other code
 while (1) {

        long msgtype = m->mtype;
        if(msgrcv(msgid, m, sizeof(message) - sizeof(m->mtype), msgtype, IPC_NOWAIT) == -1) {
            // if(close (p[1]) == -1){
            //     perror("close p[1] of the child\n");
            // } 
            //perror("\nmsgrcv");
            exit(1);
        }
        result[i] = calcolate_results(m);
        // printf("%i %i %c %i", m->id, m->num1, m->op, m->num2);
        printf("\nresult: %i\n", result[i]);

        val = result[i];

        if(write (p[1], &val, sizeof(val)) == -1) { 
            perror("write\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Child(%d) send val: %d\n", getpid(), val);
    }
 //other code
```

Now my problem is that the read in the father seems not to get the message.
When i execute the program doens't exit, it loops (stays stuch) at the read in the father.
I tried to put the read outside the for (so it should at least read the last message) but the program still stays stuck in the read.
So i would be very thankful if someone could help me.

Comment: there could be some typos in the code because i translated the code in english

Comment: Translating was a good idea. But please verify that it still behaves as described. I.e. make sure that it still is a [mcve].

Comment: @Yunnosch i only translated names of variables, functions, comments

Comment: And then you verified that it still compiles and behaves to demonstrate your problem, didn't you? Or are you expecting readers here to do that for you?

Comment: There is a difference between "there could be some typos in the code because i translated the code in english" and "there could be some typos in the code because i translated the code in english, but I verified that there are no errors caused by the typos".

Comment: Whatever, the shown code is definitely not a [mcve] anyway, this makes the question off-topic: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]."

Comment: Read [mcve] (the blue words are a link). It is not the same as "post all the code" and it is also not the same as "post just the code which you believe contains the problem".

Comment: Ok I'm sorry
i will change the question.
I asked the question because i thought that there may could be someone who knows why the read does not work, because like i said it is the first time for me using C and there could be a simple error.
The code would have been too long to post it all, but i know i m in wrong.
So again sorry and i will ask another question with a Verifiable example.

Comment: I've posted an answer listing the problems I could see with this excerpt from your code. The usual issue with `read` blocking is forgetting to `close(p[0])` in the child and `close(p[1])` in the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is full of problems.

```
switch(currentPid = fork()){
    case 0:
```

Here you need to close the read end of the pipe:

```
        close(p[0]);
```

Usually you'd have a `dup2` before `execl` here. Typically, if your child process is going to load another program, you want to redirect its stdout to the write end of the pipe, as in `dup2(p[1], 1); close(p[1]);`.

```
        execl("./child", "./child", NULL);

        return 0;
    case -1:
        printf("Error when forking\n");
        break;
    default:

        // in the father
        childrenPids[i] = currentPid; // store current child pid
        wait(NULL);
```

This `wait` call is in the wrong place. If the child outputs more data than the pipe can hold at once, you have a deadlock here (the child will block in `write`, waiting for the parent to `read` some data for the pipe before it can exit; the parent will block in `wait`, waiting for the child to exit before reading from the pipe).

It also doesn't make sense to wait for the child to exit before you've given it anything to do. Isn't this supposed to be a sort of coprocess-like design, i.e. the children should keep running along the parent, doing arithmetic on request and sending the results back?

```
        printf("\nParentpid:  %d, Childpid: %i \n", getpid(), currentPid);

        //close(p[1]);
```

Why is this `close` commented out? It's crucial that the parent process close the write end of the pipe (because otherwise reading from the read end of the pipe will block as the write end is still open somewhere (in the same process, in this case)).

```
        if(read(p[0], &val, sizeof(val) == -1){
```

This line doesn't even compile. It's missing a `)`.

```
            perror("read()\n");
            exit(1);
        }
```

You're missing a check for EOF. `read` will return 0 when it's reached the end of the data (and leave `val` uninitialized).

You should consume all available data from the pipe (until `read` returns `0`), and only then `waitpid(currentPid, NULL, 0);`.